# If one has a parametric curve $(x(t), y(t))$ under what conditions is $y$ implicitly a function of $x$?

Tags: implicit-function-theorem

If I have parametric curve $\left( x(t), y(t)\right)$ I want to know when it is the case that $y$ is implicitly a function of $x$.  I don't believe the Implicit Function Theorem applies but I'm not knowledgable enough to know if this belief is correct.  Is there an Implicit Function Theorem for parametrized curves?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x'(t_0)\ne0$, by the inverse function theorem, you can write $t=t(x)$ on an interval around $x_0=x(t_0)$. This gives you $y=(t(x))$ on that interval.